# Detect brightness level using Javascript

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas, brightness

I want to detect the **brightness level** of a webcam image.

Sending the image to the server and processing it there is not a solution because I'd like to test the brightness level right away. I'm looking for a pure Vanilla Javascript solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you consider the "brightness level"? Average brightness of all the pixels?

Comment: Yeah, that could work and classify my images @str

Comment: You will have to `getImageData`  loop through and apply a formula. If you do a search you may find some formulas out there like `let brightness = parseInt((red+ green +blue)/3);` or  `let brightness = (3*red + 4*green +blue) >>> 3`.